# Controlling Guest Account via PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am able to find Guest Account with my script if the Local account is Enabled (or Active) or not.

My question is : my question is how can I get an output like below if the guest user account is not on the server?

My desired output :

```
Name  Status  
----  ------  
Guest User NOT Found
```

Script:

```
#requires -Version 2.0
Param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [Alias('cn')][String[]]$ComputerName=$Env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('un')][String[]]$AccountName,
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('cred')][System.Management.Automation.PsCredential]$Credential
)
    
$Obj = @()

Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
{
    If($Credential)
    {
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    else
    {
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    
    Foreach($LocalAccount in $AllLocalAccounts)
    {
        $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $LocalAccount.Name
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Full Name" -Value $LocalAccount.FullName
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Caption" -Value $LocalAccount.Caption
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disabled" -Value $LocalAccount.Disabled
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value $LocalAccount.Status
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LockOut" -Value $LocalAccount.LockOut
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Changeable" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordChangeable
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Expires" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordExpires
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Required" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordRequired
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SID" -Value $LocalAccount.SID
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SID Type" -Value $LocalAccount.SIDType
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Account Type" -Value $LocalAccount.AccountType
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value $LocalAccount.Domain
        $Object|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $LocalAccount.Description
        
        $Obj+=$Object
    }

}

$obj | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Guest"} | Select-Object Name,Status
```

Comment: Your script will fail if the built-in guest account has been renamed. Better to filter on `{$_.SID -like '*-501'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

To modify the script to report if the "Guest" account isn't found, you can add a check after the "foreach" loop that populates the "$Obj" array. If no "Guest" account is found, you can create a custom object with the "Name" and "Status" properties set to "Guest" and "Not Found," respectively.

If the "Guest" account is not found, it will create a custom object with the "Name" and "Status" properties set to "Guest" and "Not Found," respectively.

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [Alias('cn')][String[]]$ComputerName=$Env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('un')][String[]]$AccountName,
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias('cred')][System.Management.Automation.PsCredential]$Credential
)
    
$Obj = @()

Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName)
{
    If($Credential)
    {
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    else
    {
        $AllLocalAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Namespace "root\cimv2" `
        -Filter "LocalAccount='$True'" -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    
    Foreach($LocalAccount in $AllLocalAccounts)
    {
        $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $LocalAccount.Name
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Full Name" -Value $LocalAccount.FullName
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Caption" -Value $LocalAccount.Caption
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Disabled" -Value $LocalAccount.Disabled
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value $LocalAccount.Status
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LockOut" -Value $LocalAccount.LockOut
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Changeable" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordChangeable
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Expires" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordExpires
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Password Required" -Value $LocalAccount.PasswordRequired
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SID" -Value $LocalAccount.SID
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SID Type" -Value $LocalAccount.SIDType
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Account Type" -Value $LocalAccount.AccountType
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value $LocalAccount.Domain
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $LocalAccount.Description
        
        $Obj += $Object
    }
}

$guestAccount = $Obj | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Guest"}

if ($guestAccount) {
    $guestAccount | Select-Object Name, Status
} else {
    $notFoundObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $notFoundObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value "Guest"
    $notFoundObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value "Not Found"
    $notFoundObject
}
```